# WP_Query 'post__not_in' condition is not working: shows all posts

Tags: php, wordpress

thank you for taking the time to review this.

I am calling a new WP_Query with the following arguments:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'post',
'post_status'    => 'publish',
'post__not_in'   => array($featured_post_ID),
'category_name'  => 'blog',
'offset'         => $offset,
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'orderby'        => 'post-date',
'order'          => 'DESC',
);
```

I know that past issues have been caused by passing a numeric post ID as a variable instead of string; to get around that I am using the following variable definition for `$featured_post_ID`:

```
$featured_post_ID = '"'.$post_ID.'"';
```

When I run this query, it outputs the post I am trying to exclude.

Here is a [Transcript of output of the WP_Query](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O4qXyI-lZJLcCZIYpurAb7FixSrb6kK8/view?usp=sharing) to save space. Looks like `post__not_in` is recognized in the query, but has no effect on the output.

Can anyone advise why this might be happening, or how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried just using `'post__not_in'   => array($post_ID),`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply!

Yes, I tried that and it causes the whole $args array to be ignored, and the query is not executed.

Comment: Have you dumped `$post_ID` to confirm there is actually a value in there?

Comment: Hello, and thanks for chiming in! Yes, I have. It is reading "2194" in the $featured_post_ID variable and 2194 in $post_ID.